# Redux state is not updating real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am making a signup form and I want to navigate a user to the login page when the signup is successful. On the signup page, I want to get the updated state. In the `signup` handler, I am not getting updated state (`status`) in real-time although the status is updating outside the function.

Signup Component

```
const Signup = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      navigate('/home')
    }
  }, [])

  const signupForm = [
    {
      label: "Name",
      InputIcon: FaUserAlt,
      width: '100%',
      handleInput: (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value)
      }
    },
    {
      label: "Email",
      InputIcon: FaEnvelope,
      width: '100%',
      handleInput: (e) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value)
      }
    },
    {
      label: "Phone",
      InputIcon: FaPhoneAlt,
      width: '100%',
      handleInput: (e) => {
        setPhone(e.target.value)
      }
    },
  ]

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const { status } = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.auth;
  })

  console.log(status);

  const signup = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const user = {
      name,
      email,
      phone,
      password
    }

    await dispatch(signupUser(user))
    console.log(status);
    // if (status == 'success') {
    //   navigate('/')
    // }
  }

  return (
    <div className='form-container'>
      <img src={userImage} alt='user' />
      <form>
        <h2>Sign up</h2>
        {
          signupForm.map((data, i) => {
            return <OutlinedTextField
              key={i}
              style={{ width: data.width }}
              label={data.label}
              InputIcon={data.InputIcon}
              onChangeFunc={data.handleInput}
            />
          })
        }

        <OutlinedPasswordTextField
          style={{ width: '100%' }}
          label={'Password'}
          InputIcon={FaLock}
          onChangeFunc={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />

        <div className='btn-container'>
          <AppButton text={status == 'loading' ? <CircularProgress color='inherit' size="15px" /> : 'Sign up'}
            disabled={status == 'loading' ? true : false}
            onClickFunc={signup}
            style={{ width: '80px' }}
          />

          <Link to="/">Login</Link>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Authentication Slice

```js
const STATUSES = {
  SUCCESS: 'success',
  LOADING: 'loading',
  FAIL: 'fail'
}

export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk('user/signup', async (user) => {
  const data = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/signup', user)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      toast.error(err.response.data.message)
      throw new Error(err.response.data.message)
    })
  console.log(data);
  return data
})

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'product',
  initialState: {
    data: [],
    status: STATUSES,
    loading: false,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(signupUser.pending, (state, action) => {
      console.log(action, state)
      state.status = STATUSES.LOADING
    })
    builder.addCase(signupUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log(action, state)
      state.status = STATUSES.SUCCESS
      state.data = action.payload
    })
    builder.addCase(signupUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      console.log(action, state)
      state.status = STATUSES.FAIL
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that the selected `status` state is closed over in callback scope and will not ever update during the life of the `signup` callback. In other words, it is a stale closure over the `status` value.

A secondary issue I see in the `signupUser` action is not returning the fetched data correctly; nothing is returned from the `.then`-able that logs `res.data`.

> ```
> const data = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/signup', user)
>   .then(res => {
>     console.log(res.data);
>     // nothing returned here, data above is undefined!
>   })
> ```

You are using an asynchronous Thunk action which returns a Promise. You can await the dispatched `signupUser` to resolve. Use the `.unwrap` function to check if the asynchronous action was successful or not. See [Checking Errors  after Dispatching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#checking-errors-after-dispatching) and [Handling Thunk Errors](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors) for details.

```js
export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/signup",
  async (user, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/signup', user);
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    } catch(err) {
      toast.error(err.response.data.message);
      rejectWithValue(err.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);
```

```js
const signup = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const user = {
    name,
    email,
    phone,
    password
  };

  try {
    await dispatch(signupUser(user)).unwrap();
    navigate("/");
  } catch(error) {
    // handle/ignore any failed user signup attempts
  }
};
```

Comment: I can also see the API response in then catch of my signup API, but using unwrap and navigating in try block works for me. 
Thank you so much @Drew Reese

Answer (score 1):

```
const Signup = () => {

  // ...

  const { status } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'success') {
      navigate('/')
    }
  }, [status])

  const signup = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const user = {
      name,
      email,
      phone,
      password
    }

    await disptach(signupUser(user))
  }

  return (
    // ...
  )
}
```

You should check the status inside the Signup with useSelector. If your status changes you can re-trigger your navigate inside the useEffect with the dependency array.

Comment: If I navigate in useEffect, surely it will navigate to the '/' but if I go back to the same (sign up) page the useEffect runs again, gets the success status, and will not allow coming back to signup page.